# Find the density of the product of its coordinates

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A point with coordinates (x,y) is uniformly distributed over the square
 |x| ≤ 1, |y| ≤ 1. Find the density of the product of its coordinates

Comment: I've tried drawing the square and drawing the graph (y = 1/x), problem is i dont know what limits to integrate

Comment: Fix a $c\in(0,1]$ (you can later handle the negative values by a symmetry argument). Find the points on the perimeter of the unit square that intersect the graph of $y=c/x$. There are four of them, and that graph has two components. Stare at the figure and determine the region where $xy<c$. Using those intersection points calculate the integral that gives you the area of the region. Divide that by the area of the square. Now you have the cumulative probability function of $xy$. Take its derivative to get the density function....

Comment: From the graph isn't there just one point that the perimeter of the square intersects with the function y = 1/x? thats at the point (1,1)

Comment: You want the intersection with the interior of the square (not the perimeter) with the function is $y=\color{blue}{c}/x$ for supported values of $c$ to evaluate $f_{X\cdotp Y}(c)$.

Comment: Alright I've figured out the four intersection points and done the integration on the positive side, if I do the same for the negative side isn't it going to give me the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Can you show that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ both follow a uniform distribution on $[-1;1]$ ? Can you then write the density of $X$ and $Y$ ?
- Can you show that $X$ and $Y$ are independant ?
- Can you write the density of $Z=XY$ using the density of $X\times Y$ ?

Comment: Are these hints for me? Or for you to solve the question? I'm confused

Comment: They are hints for you to solve the question...